# SQL Server 2012 Express returnes duplicate results in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

I've discovered a weird behaviour in our MS SQL Server 2012 Express instance at work.

One of our employees was saying that she is always getting duplicate results in her programm.

It turns out that the root cause of the problem seems to be one or several views.

**One example:**

We have one view returning records from 4 tables:

```
SELECT dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.monr,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.art,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.VkGr,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.modbez,
       dbo.Logos_tbl.Pfad,
       dbo.Logos_tbl.Dateiname_Bild,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.vgr,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.Them,
       dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.js,
       dbo.PRLK_fnr1_vw.fnr,
       dbo.PRLK_fnr1_vw.whr,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.Land,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.PRLand,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.SummevonAnzahl,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.Liefertermin,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.EK,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.UVP,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.Preisliste,
       dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.Spr
FROM dbo.Logos_tbl
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PRLK_fnr1_vw
                      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw
                                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl ON dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.vgr = dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.vgr
                                                                             ON dbo.PRLK_fnr1_vw.land = dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.PRLand
                                                                            AND dbo.PRLK_fnr1_vw.prlkid = dbo.Kollektionsversand_Preisliste_vw.Preisliste
                                       ON dbo.Logos_tbl.VKGr = dbo.Vertreter_Etiketten_Druck_tbl.vgr;
```

This view always worked without any problems until the start of this week.

But now, selecting everything from this view with...

`Select * FROM Vertreter_Etiketten_druck_Preisliste_vw`

... returns the correct records, but two times for each record.

The SQL string is prefectly working, because putting the string into a new query and running it, returns the records distinct.

---

This happened to several other views in our system, so I guess the problem is caused by the SQL Server?

We've restarted the whole VM yesterday, but to no effect.

There are also no open or pending updates on either Windows (Windows Server 2012 R2) or the SQL Server instance.

---

Thank you all in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Why continue to use SQL Server 2012 Express, out of interest? 2012 ran completely out of support last week, and upgrading Express instances of SQL Server is free, so there is really no express to not be using a fully supported version of the application.

Comment: Also, as a FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: *"This happened to several other views in our system, so I guess the problem is caused by the SQL Server?"* if the `VIEW` definition hasn't changed, I doubt it. More likely your data has changed.

Comment: the most likely situation is that your join condition is matched on multiple rows, and so you get multiple rows in your result set.

Comment: That `VIEW`, as well, looks like it's a `VIEW` that is querying `VIEW`s (with object names like `PRLK_fnr1_vw`). This can often be a (very) bad habit, as SQL Server will struggle to optimise nested `VIEW`s. You are far better off repeating the logic, not nesting `VIEW`s. Have a read of [Is nested view a good database design?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design). Point 1 seems very relevant here too: *"Nested Views are harder to understand and debug"*; with the nesting involved, *you* (not us) are going to have a harder time debugging.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the quick response. We will be upgrading our instance soon to a SQL Server 2019 (not express) instance. I'll have a look at the 3 part naming, also thanks for that. But how can you explain that the view returns duplicate results and the same SQL string in a seperate query is returning it correctly?

Comment: If you have a `VIEW` and a SQL statement that are returning different results, then the `VIEW` and the SQL statement are not the same or you are not running the queries in the same database/instance, @Timinator0815 , it's as simple as that.

Comment: @TZHX I've checked that, it is correct. Every record of the joined tables are unique. Also running the query outside the view brings up the correct results.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I completely understand that you don't believe me. I also wouldn't have believed myself, if I haven't seen it. The SQL statement and the `View` are the same and are running on the same database. Me and my colleagues have checked it several times over and over. That's why we think it's some kind of bug (because it doesn't make sense to us).

Comment: I would suggest start by unnesting your `VIEW`s, @Timinator0815 .

Comment: I agree with @Larnu that the most likely explanation is that there has been a change in your views, or a change in your data, or you are selecting from different data in each case.  Is there some regular housekeeping process that should have been run but didn't? SQL server has been around for years and is used in millions of installations. The likelihood of this being caused by a bug in SQL Server is vanishingly small.

Comment: As you are using right outer joins all the way through, the problem may be that there are duplicate records in the rightmost table. ROJ always returns every record from the right-hand table, even if they are duplicates.

Comment: The only thing not mentioned yet that I could think off: Have you checked what sort of SET settings each of the views have? Are they the same as the database default? You can check those by making a right click on the view and select SCRIPT AS CREATE...

Comment: Thank you all for your clues and tips. We have found the problem. It was a data problem in a very important table. That's why it caused other queries to have wrong results. And on top of that, our naming convention on the views caused us to confuse some of them, leading to wrong conclusions. But we'll improve our structure in the future, implementing your suggestions. Sorry for the confusion, wish you all a nice day